# What is the difference between the abc.db and abc.sqlite for android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, metadata

i have seen many android database application.

Some of the application have its database with .sqlite extension while some have .db extension.

What is the difference betwwen those both ? Should it both contain different things ?

Please help me for that.

And what should be the best to use for the android database ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.sqlite file is as the name implies a file that contains SQLite database.
.db is the file extension used by Oracle, Paradox and XoftSpySE databases

You can name your SQLite database whatever you want. The content is not determined by the file ending but by a sequence of bytes which start every [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html) (3) file:

0x53 0x51 0x4c 0x69 0x74 0x65 0x20 0x66 0x6f 0x72 0x6d 0x61 0x74 0x20 0x33 0x00

In other words, it could be the same database content. There is no difference, as long as the creator did not put other bytes in it.

Answer (score 3):

**extensions doesn't matter.** you may even omit any extension to your database file. Its just for the understanding of developer to know which file type it is. At least that's what i believe :)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a database, you only is are going to give a name to the database which you will create. so So the extension does not make any difference.. Sqlite SQLite browser will recognise recognize it anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

yes extension doesn't matters but SQLite is a database which used for android and other DB's works for all database.

but let me clear one thing .sqlite shows SQLite database. .db is the file used by oracle, self contained db dumpp of mysql etc etc